# find all symbolic links in a directory tree pointing outside that tree

Tags: symlink

I frequently move directory trees to other locations or copy their tarballs to other machines, and I would like to have a method to check whether any symlinks in a directory tree *A* point to locations outside of *A* since these will be broken in the moved / copied directory.

Answer (score 7):

You want a program called `realpath`, used in conjunction with `find`.

E.g.:

```
find . -type l -exec realpath {} \; | grep -v "^$(pwd)"
```

Comment: The incantation you provide only reports the offending target location, not the symlink that points to it. As such I have removed my acceptance. Please see my "answer" below: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308899/24044 and if you are happy with it (or improve it) I will delete my "answer" and accept your question again.

Answer (score 2):

With zsh:

```
cd -P -- "$dir"
for i (**/*(ND@)) [[ $i:A = $PWD/* ]] || [[ $i:A = $PWD ]] || print -r -- "$i => $i:A"
```

Now, if the directory is `/foo` and you have `/foo/bar` that's a symlink to `/foo/baz`, that's a link whose target is in /foo, but once moved, the link will still be broken, so you may want also to match symlinks to absolute paths.

But even then,  a `bar => ../foo/baz` in `/foo` would be an issue (false negative), so would a `a => b` where `b` is a symlink outside the tree (false positive, depending on how you want to look at it)

Answer (score 2):

Use [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/) to create another view of that directory tree.

```
mkdir /tmp/view
bindfs /some/directory /tmp/view
```

Then use the [symlinks](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/symlinks8.html) utility (shipped by many distributions, or compile it from [source](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/symlinks/symlinks_1.2.orig.tar.gz)) to detect cross-filesystem links.

```
symlinks -r /tmp/view | sed -n 's/^\(absolute\|other_fs\): //p'
```

(Note that parsing the output assumes that your symbolic links and their targets do not contain newlines, nor do paths to symbolic links contain the substring  `->` .) That same utility can also convert absolute symlinks to relative (but you'd want to do that from the original location).

Answer (score 2):

I had to tweak a little the answer given by @bahamat to make it work.

The version provided simply reported the offending absolute location but not the symlink that points to it.

Here's what I used (I am sure it can be improved):

```
for f in $(find . -type l ); do echo -n $(realpath $f) && echo -n "|" && echo $f ; done | grep -v "^$(pwd)" | cut -d \| -f 2
```

Comment: I found this to be the most useful script: `for f in $(find . -type l); do echo $(realpath -m -q $f) '<-' $f; done | grep-v "^$(pwd)"` (most notably `-m` and `-q` which filters out broken and non-external links)

Answer (score 1):

GNU coreutils provedes `realpath`, which resolves symlinks. With this, you could compare each symlink's target to the current working directory with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . | while read filename
do
  if realpath $filename | grep -E "^$PWD" > /dev/null
  then
    echo 'this file is safe'
  else
    echo 'this file links externally'
  fi
done
```

Comment: Several problems: no `-type l`, no `-r` option to `read`, IFS not sanitized for `read`, `$filename` not quoted, `$PWD` treated as a regular expression, paths with newline characters not accounted for, `/foobar` would be matched for `$PWD` == "/foo"