# What is a good command for moving a directory containing relative symbolic links to files outside the directory?

Tags: shell, symlink, directory-structure, coreutils

I like to use relative symlinks when possible because they stay valid even when my filesystem is mounted in a non-root location, for example if I am [accessing it remotely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS).

However, if I move a directory which contains relative symlinks, in general those links become invalid.

I am looking for a command that I can use to move a whole directory (tree), rewriting only those relative symlinks that point outside the directory so that they still point to the same files.

*There is a related question on Stack Overflow, [How do I move a relative symbolic link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523159/how-do-i-move-a-relative-symbolic-link). Also, here on Unix & Linux, [find all symbolic links in a directory tree pointing outside that tree](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49958/find-all-symbolic-links-in-a-directory-tree-pointing-outside-that-tree), and (referring to a much harder problem) [is there some kind of symbolic links that support moving or renaming the target file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81412/is-there-some-kind-of-symbolic-links-that-support-moving-or-renaming-the-target).*

For example, a command called `mv-rel` which behaves as follows (the other commands being their GNU coreutils versions):

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch bar
$ ln -sr bar foo/
$ touch foo/flob
$ ln -sr foo/flob foo/qux
$ ls -gG foo/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 6 Dec  1 00:05 bar -> ../bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Dec  1 00:24 flob
lrwxrwxrwx 1 4 Dec  1 00:24 qux -> flob

$ mkdir baz
$ mv-rel foo/ baz
$ ls -gG baz/foo/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 6 Dec  1 00:05 bar -> ../../bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Dec  1 00:24 flob
lrwxrwxrwx 1 4 Dec  1 00:24 qux -> flob
```

Unless I'm missing something, this also seems like it would be a useful command-line option to the 'mv' command (maybe also 'cp'). But for the purposes of this question I am looking for something that exists now, or a simple portable script that implements this functionality.

Comment: Check if rsync has a symlink handling option that works for you.

Comment: Not seeing it...

Comment: Have you tried a gui file manager or does it have to be a command?

Answer (score 2):

I finally wrote a solution and posted it on Github:

https://github.com/minTaqa/mvrel

It is not currently as flexible as "mv", in that only two arguments are allowed, and the second argument must be a directory. However, I found it useful for moving something that had a lot of relative symlinks. I wanted to make sure that it could deal with spaces, newlines, and other riffraff in filenames, so this was also a chance for me to learn about Bats, the TAP-compliant testing framework written in Bash, where I put some unit tests to convince myself that everything is working.

The script itself is also written in Bash. I thought this would be easiest and most portable language for the task, but I ended up having to work around things like the fact that [command substitution deletes trailing newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5322980/5087283) (a problem if you have filenames with trailing newlines, which is mostly theoretical but still annoying). Then [there is `find ... -print0` and `IFS= read -rd ''`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8677566/5087283), plus lots of quotes and "--" arguments -- stuff that wouldn't be needed in a slightly lower-level scripting language like Perl. I also wouldn't be doing [string manipulation by parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34520349/5087283) in Perl. Anyway you can rewrite it in Perl or even C if you like; as it is, it is reasonably short in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly destructive method: replace the relative links with absolute links:

```
cd foo
for f in *; do
    if [[ -h $f ]]    # True if file is a symbolic link.
    then
        abs=$(readlink -f "$f") && rm "$f" && ln -s "$abs" "$f"
    fi
done
```